# Terraform : difference between referencing using local and resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following piece of code which creates bucket and enables versioning.

Here I am referencing bucket using locals

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "sample" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

In this code I am referencing using

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "sample" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sample.bucket
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

I think both does the same work, but my mentor said writing with resource is better code as it decreases the chances of errors because using locals terraform wont understand the dependencies snd might provision versioning before provisioning bucket.

My point is I think terraform is smart enough to resolve dependencies, is it still true when we reference using locals.

Tere is an article about this ( in japanese ) https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/dependency-in-terraform/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mentor is correct.  `aws_s3_bucket.sample.bucket` is better then `local.bucket_name`. This is because it makes code easier to maintain and modify. For example, if you have code as follows:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "sample" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
}
```

Then any changes in `aws_s3_bucket`, to let say

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}
```

will require you to **manual change** `aws_s3_bucket_versioning` as well. Its easy if you have small code, but if not, then this can be quite troublesome.

In contrast, if you have

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "sample" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sample.bucket
}
```

then changing `aws_s3_bucket`

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sample" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}
```

will **automatically** translate to the rest of code. You do not have to manually change `aws_s3_bucket_versioning` and fix bucket name.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, this implication of using resource as a reference is understandable in terms of maintaining the code, however I want to know more details in terms of dependencies resolution using local or resource reference. 
How does terraform treat dependecies when using one reference over the another

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean. local variables are not part of any resource dependencies. You have to make sure yourself that all local values are correct.

Comment: Can you read this once, maybe you will understand what I want to convey? 
 https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/dependency-in-terraform/

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Sadly, I can't read Japanese.

Comment: lmao, if you can use, google chrome and use translate, because I really I want to understand the inner working of this